# How to hide Text from UILabel in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to display a set of numbers on a `UILabel` sequentially.

**For example:** I have an array with 5 numbers and each time I want one number from the array to be displayed for 2 seconds on the screen then disappear and then the next number…

This is what i have done so far, but it is not quite what I want. The code below just displays the last number in the array for 2 seconds and then disappears.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];      

     NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
     for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            NSNumber *temp;
            temp = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [self displayNumber:temp];

            [myLabel setHidden:NO];
    }
}

-(void) displayNumber: (NSNumber *) myNumber{
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myNumber];
    NSTimer *myTimer;
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(hideLabel) userInfo:Nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void) hideLabel{
    [myLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

I thought about having 5 functions and each gets called sequentially after 2 seconds, but that is very inefficient.

Are there any other ways I can do this?

Comment: What's not working with the code you currently have? You could just use `sleep(2)`

Comment: Well, the code that I have now just displays the last number in the array for 2 seconds and then disappears.

Comment: calling sleep(2) on the main thread would block your app and all interaction for 2 seconds

Comment: @rist Of course. I just wanted to make him aware of another method. This is by no means a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this method

Hope it will works for you what you want

1) Define

```
NSMutableArray* myArray , int repeatCount; and NSTimer *myTimer in .h file and set its property;
```

2)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];     
     //This will initialize your timer
     myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(showLabel) userInfo:Nil repeats:NO];
     //This will trigger your timer 
     [myTimer fire];
     //Your timer will run in a loop
     [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];   

     myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void) displayNumber: (NSNumber *) myNumber{
     myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myNumber];
}

-(void) showLabel{        
     if(repeatCount >= [myArray count])
     {
         repeatCount = 0;
     }
     NSNumber *temp = [myArray objectAtIndex:repeatCount];
     repeatCount ++;
     [self displayNumber:temp];   
     [myLabel setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: What does the last line do?

Comment: I have changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you can use timer with counter.

Create 3 properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int counter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

Set them in viewDidLoad: and start timer(with repetition):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _counter = 0;
    _array = @[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(nextLabel) userInfo:Nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Update label:

```
- (void)nextLabel{
    if (_counter == [_array count]) {
        //stop in the end of array
        [_timer invalidate];
        return;
    }
    [_label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _array[_counter]]];
    _counter++;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, it's too in efficient, if my array has 100 elements.

Comment: Hm, and what's wrong with this solution? Just create _array with 100 elements and everything will be fine

Comment: @user2771150 Hm, do you want to show array element for 2 seconds, then hide it for 2 seconds and then show next?

Comment: yeah, it is not very efficient. Also, this solution wouldn't work if i don't know what is in the array. The array might hold random numbers.

Comment: I know, I don't use nothing from array, just show numbers from array element for element. I use only array count to stop in the end, and show proper element _array[_counter], you can try to set any numbers to array of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Initialize the timer when you want to change the first number
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeNumber:) userInfo:@{@"currentNumber" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]} repeats:NO];

-(void)changeNumber:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSDictionary * dictionary = [timer userInfo];
    int number = [(NSNumber *)[dictionary objectForKey:@"currentNumber"] integerValue];
    if (number < [numbersArray count])
    {
        myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [numbersArray objectAtIndex:number]];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeNumber:) userInfo:@{@"currentNumber" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:number + 1]} repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, if the numbers in the array are not in sequential order. For example, the elements in the array might be [2,99,55,1,32].

Comment: Updated my answer. `numbersArray` is the array containing the numbers you want displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the array with NSNumber instances to the below method

```
- (void)updateLabelWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    if ([array count] != 0)
    {
        myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array firstObject]];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateLabelWithArray:)
                   withObject:array
                   afterDelay:2.0f];
    }
}
```

This should do.

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this helps u .. :)

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad 
   { 
     [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     [super viewDidLoad];

      myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],[NSNumber numberWithInt:6],[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:10], nil]; //your array contains any number you want

     index = 0; //showing the numbers from 0th index to last indx
     [self.myLabel setHidden:NO];

     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(DisplayFortwoSec) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//call the method reguraly for 2 sec
   }

   - (void)DisplayFortwoSec
   {
      [self.myLabel setHidden:YES];
       if(index == ([myArray count] - 1))
        index = 0;//other stuffs to come out of loop like invalidating the timer
       [self.myLabel setHidden:NO];
       NSNumber *num = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
       NSString *strNum = [num stringValue];
       self.myLabel.text = strNum;
       [self.myLabel setHidden:NO];
       index ++;

   }
```